# java spring inheritance for grandchild (suplier/client vs foreign/national)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, inheritance

Haven't been able to find any example on how to use InheritanceType.JOINED and two levels of inheritance, so I'm not sure how to do it. Been trying for a few days (not very eagerly, as you may imagine).

I need to create classes to do something like this:

[image]

I was thinking about having a "kind" `@DiscriminatorColumn` in person and an "Origin" `@DiscriminatorColumn` in Supplier and in Client or any other kind. The problem is I couldn't find a way to have two values for `@DiscriminatorValue` in one table.

So my question is: What is the supposed way to do something like this?

Thank you all.

Ely.

P.S. In some classes of the "kind" level (Supplier, client, etc) could need to use something different than National" or "Foreign" for a child.

Comment: Do you really need separate java classes for each type?  Couldn't you just use two booleans; one for supplier/client and one for foreign/national?

Comment: This software is for a Mexican company, so the "National" person has one kind of address that is completely different than a foreign one and I'm looking for a way to have the minimum number of "unused" attributes per kind of row in the database table

Comment: So still boolean value would be a solution imho. A boolean in Person class isSupplier and National and Foreign inherited. So you do not need extra supplier and client class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your criteria is to minimize an unused space then `JOINED` strategy is the way you should go. An example approach may look like this:

```java
@Entity // or @MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ORIGIN", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Person { ... }
```

Optionally you may remove `discriminatorType` thus defaulting it to string.

Both `Supplier` and `Client` entities acts as mapped superclasses (so they are not persistable, cannot be instantiated and queried, cannot be the target of a relationship). Their state and behavior is inherited by the concrete entities which are persistable.

```java
@MappedSuperclass // or @Entity
public abstract class Supplier extends Person { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name = "NATIONAL_SUPPLIER")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class National extends Supplier { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOREIGN_SUPPLIER")
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class Foreign extends Supplier { ... }
```

```java
@MappedSuperclass // or @Entity
public abstract class Client extends Person { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name = "NATIONAL_CLIENT")
@DiscriminatorValue("3")
public class National extends Client { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOREIGN_CLIENT")
@DiscriminatorValue("4")
public class Foreign extends Client { ... }
```

Obviously such an hierarchy can be extended both horizontally and vertically but it's worth to mention that the deeper or wider hierarchy is the more expensive querying/inserting may become (in other words: querying/inserting across hierarchy would require more joins on each new level).

Comment: Does all the intermediate levels of specialization need to have the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation?

Comment: No they don't. It's enough to have only one `@MappedSuperclass` in a hierarchy. For example: 1) you can add concrete class `AsianClient extends ForeignClient` that acts as an entity or 2) you can define `Person` as _mapped superclass_ instead of `Supplier` and `Person` so they can act as _entities_ (persistable) or _transient classes_ (not persistable). Keep in mind that a mapped superclass **cannot** be instantiated/persisted/queried/inserted. It's up to you which classes are stored in the underlying database and which share the state with descendants. I have updated my answer accordingly.